# React Native detect pointer tool

Tags: android, react-native

In Android the `MotionEvent` [knows](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent#getToolType(int)) the tool type of a pointer. It can detect "Finger", "Stylus", "Mouse" and even "Eraser".

Is there any equivalent functionality in React Native that can get the pointer type from `GestureResponderEvent`? I'm targeting Android only (no iOS, Windows, Web) so is there a way to get the info specifically for Android systems?